# How to cast a function input to a smart pointer in c++?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, void-pointers

I am using a function with "void* fdata" as one of its inputs. I defined a structure called data2 and can pass a defined structure variable to the function by using &alldata2, where alldata2 is the name of the structure variable defined under data2.

My question is how to cast the intput in f(..., void* fdata,...) to a smart pointer in the body of the function f? The function f is inside a loop, where I also used "#pragma omp parallel for the num_threads(3)" for the loop.

I can use the following command in the function to create a raw pointer, called dp2, to alldata2:

```
double f(..., void* fdata, ...)
{
data2* dp2 =  (data2 *)(fdata);
...
}
```

But the program seems to have memory leakage and I suspect it is caused by creation of dp2 in recursive evaluations of the function f. Any help will be greatly appreciated! I am using Visual Studio 2012 Express.

Some methods I've tried but not working include:

1. In the function, write

   data2* dp2 = new data2();
   dp2 = (data2*)(fdata);

And delete dp2 later before the "return" command.

2. std::unique_ptr *dp2(static_cast(fdata))

Comment: unless you are dealing with C interface, don't use `void *`. you can have something like `std::shared_ptr<void>` if you can't use template and want to erase type information

Comment: re <<using a function with "void* fdata">>, why? that's generally not a good idea. to wit, you got problems.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<data2> dp2(reinterpret_cast<data2*>(fdata));`

Comment: @BryanChen. Thanks! This could be a way to solve it. Will try later.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf This is just one way to pass data to the function.

Comment: @Brandon Thanks! I forgot to mention in the post that I tried your method earlier but it's not working.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working". There's no way `unique_ptr` would fail.. You'll need to explain what you mean.

Comment: @Brandon I can build the solution in Visual Studio using your method, but the .exe file stopped to work and Windows closed the program:(

Comment: You might have a stack overflow from recursion or you're deleting a pointer that isn't allocated. There's many reasons your program can stop working. You'd have to show more code or an example that we can run.

Comment: @Brandon Stack overflow is also a possibility. Without using smart pointers, the program runs fine probably for the first hour, then it quickly consumes almost all 16 gb memory on my desktop. Is this a typical symptom of stack overlfow?  The program has hundreds of code and uses Armadillo, nlopt, cubature (multidimensional integration), and I am not sure you can run it instantly on your machine. Do you mind if I sent you the code to take a quick look?

Comment: @Brandon Given the way I am currently using the in the program  double f(..., void* fdata, ...)
{
data2* dp2 =  (data2 *)(fdata);
...
}  Will dp2 be automatically cleared after the function return the results?

Answer (score 0):

I realized all I want is to have access to the content of the void pointer in the function f(..., void* fdata,...).

By replace the pointer dp2 in the function with ((data2*)(fdata)), the program works without creating a pointer. Possible memory leakage concern associate with pointers is gone.

Thanks again to all people who replied:)